# SSIS 2012 Flat File Destination Header - Second line gets a pipe in the beginning of the row

Tags: file, ssis, header, flat

I am trying to insert a header row in my Flat File I am creating with SSIS 2012. I am using the Header property in the Flat File Destination (click on the data flow and go to the `properties -> expressions`).

I am able to insert the header but for some reason the second line (which is the first line of data) gets a pipe as a first character. My file has pipe as a column delimeter. My header is static and should read: `H|1574`. I tried all these combinations of the carriage return:

```
"H|1574\r\n"
"H|1574\r"
"H|1574\n"
```

They all work the same way. I get my header in the first row but the first character in the second row is the pipe or "|".

What is wrong in my expression?

[Header expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3yvB.jpg)
[Data file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e98HK.jpg)

Comment: can you add sample data for your input .?
what is source ? is it table ? or another flatfile ?
add sample data and what you want in to flatfile.

Comment: Question is not clear. Provide sample input

Comment: I added the header expression along with the data file snapshot showing the pipe in the front of the first data row.